# Java int to String - Integer.toString(i) vs new Integer(i).toString()

Tags: java, string, int

Sometimes java puzzles me.
I have a huge amount of *int* initializations to make.

What's the *real* difference?

1. `Integer.toString(i)`
2. `new Integer(i).toString()`

Comment: I would just use `"" + 42`, but hey, that's me. Form #2 will result in a new integer object (for most values of i) as an intermediate. It is also more typing.

Comment: @pst: if the intermediate object is an issue for you, then `"" + 42` isn't any better, as it requires an intermediate `StringBuilder` which is quite a lot heavier than an `Integer`.

Comment: "" + 42 might work, but is a bad idea.  Folks like me will come look at your code and try to figure out what the heck happened to the empty string.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `"" + 42` because in the case of appending strings of integers you may end up adding the values and not realizing it.

Comment: @alavin89, we're talking about Java here, that definitely isn't going to happen. A valid warning in the case of JS and similar languages though.

Comment: If you don't like a lot of typing, then you probably shouldn't be programming in Java.

Comment: I personally prefer `String.valueOf()` because it can be used for any type.

Comment: How about using a formatted string: String.format("%d", i);

Answer (score 562, accepted):

[`Integer.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--) calls the static method in the class [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). It does not need an instance of `Integer`.

If you call [`new Integer(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-) you create an instance of type `Integer`, which is a full Java object encapsulating the value of your int. Then you call the `toString` method on it to ask it to return a string representation of *itself*.

If all you want is to print an `int`, you'd use the first one because it's lighter, faster and doesn't use extra memory (aside from the returned string).

If you want an object representing an integer value—to put it inside a collection for example—you'd use the second one, since it gives you a full-fledged object to do all sort of things that you cannot do with a bare `int`.

Answer (score 97):

`new Integer(i).toString()` first creates a (redundant) wrapper object around `i` (which itself may be a wrapper object `Integer`).

`Integer.toString(i)` is preferred because it doesn't create any unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 48):

Another option is the static [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-) method.

```
String.valueOf(i)
```

It *feels* slightly more right than `Integer.toString(i)` to me. When the type of i changes, for example from `int` to `double`, the code will stay correct.

Comment: Yes. Unless you must use RADIX (in that case you must use Integer.toString)

Answer (score 14):

1. `new Integer(i).toString();`

   This statement creates the object of the Integer and then call its methods `toString(i)` to **return the String representation of Integer's value**.
2. `Integer.toString(i);`

   It **returns the String object representing the specific int (integer)**, but here `toString(int)` is a `static` method.

Summary is in first case it returns the objects string representation, where as in second case it returns the string representation of integer.

Answer (score 14):

I also highly recommend using

```
int integer = 42;
String string = integer + "";
```

Simple and effective.

Comment: this is definitely bad form, because it both relies on a fairly subtle part of the Java language and is less efficient than Integer.toString(i). See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string)

Comment: This could be inefficient. I suggest using some conventional choices like Integer.toString or String.valueOf. Check here http://javadevnotes.com/java-integer-to-string-examples

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to do things in such an unintuitive manner. More obvious choices like `Integer.toString()` might use some extra keystrokes, but are much clearer, which is crucial when you want to maintain the code.

Comment: Wouldn't this automatically call integer variable's `toString()` method?

Answer (score 13):

Although I like fhucho's recommendation of

```
String.valueOf(i)
```

The irony is that this method actually calls

```
Integer.toString(i)
```

Thus, use `String.valueOf(i)` if you like how it reads and you don't need radix, but also knowing that it is less efficient than `Integer.toString(i)`.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of performance measurement, if you are considering the time performance then the **Integer.toString(i);** is expensive if you are calling less than 100 million times. Else if it is more than 100 million calls then the **new Integer(10).toString()** will perform better.

Below is the code through u can try to measure the performance,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            int MAX_ITERATION = 10000000;
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATION; ++i) {
            String s = Integer.toString(10);
        }
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("diff1: " + (endtime-starttime));

        starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITERATION; ++i) {
            String s1 = new Integer(10).toString();
        }
        endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("diff2: " + (endtime-starttime));
    }
```

In terms of memory, the

> new Integer(i).toString();

will take more memory as it will create the object each time, so memory fragmentation will happen.

Comment: I pasted this code in IntelliJ IDEA and got a warning: "`new Integer(10).toString() can be simplified to Integer.toString(10)`"

Comment: This code works for me.  I get about 420 milliseconds for Integer.toString(10) and 525 milliseconds for new Integer(10).toString()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java ...

Comment: Would of helped to warmup first, otherwise the results aren't valid!

Comment: If you say one is expensive in one case, and the other is better in the other case, that means the the other is better/inexpensive in all situation.

Answer (score 2):

Better:

```
Integer.valueOf(i).toString()
```

Comment: I think this is better, because as @Dhiraj pointed out that in terms of memory, the

"new Integer(i).toString();"

will take more memory because it creates a new object instead of just getting the Integer value and converting that to a string.

Comment: @Lucy Integer.valueOf(i) returns a new Integer, so there's no difference

Comment: You're not providing an answer to the question at all. The question is what is the difference between blah and blah, not what is a better replacement for blah.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is just concatenate `""` with integer:

```
int i = 100;

String s = "" + i;
```

now `s` will have `100` as string value.

Answer (score 1):

Here 
`Integer.toString` calls the static method in the class Integer. It does not require the object to call.

If you call `new Integer(i)` you first create an instance of type Integer, which is a full Java object encapsulating the value of your int i. Then you call the `toString` method on it to ask it to return a string representation of itself.

Answer (score 0):

1.`Integer.toString(i)`

```
Integer i = new Integer(8);
    // returns a string representation of the specified integer with radix 8
 String retval = i.toString(516, 8);
System.out.println("Value = " + retval);
```

2.`new Integer(i).toString()`

```
 int i = 506;

String str = new Integer(i).toString();
System.out.println(str + " : " + new Integer(i).toString().getClass());////506 : class java.lang.String
```