# Pass two different datatypes as parameters in update command

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update a table that accepts two parameters (Integer and String) in where clause.

If I write a query that has no problem where I can directly write those in where clause but I am doing this programmatically where `Insert` method of SQLite in Android need to be passed the values.

Insert accepts only `String` arguments but I need to pass one String and one Integer, how do I achieve this?

```
Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase().update(st.tablename,
 st.update(buy,Buyprice , Sell, Sellprice), (st.column2+" =? and "+ st.column3+" =? "),(new 
String[] {getdate,name}));
```

In above command `getdate` is `Integer` and `name` is `String` but it is giving the error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to String

Comment: Can't you use String.valueOf(getDate)? should be fine.

Comment: @TheRedFox Thanks for your reply.. but column is `Integer` how can it compare String

Comment: doesn't matter it will compare anyway since the all query is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you can keep intenger into String array? This is not possible.

So you need to typecast the integer.

like

```
String[] {String.valueOf(getdate),name}
```

It will be handled to check your integer column. No worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but column is Integer how can it compare String value and will the query accepts comparing integer with a string in where clause

Comment: You pass where values into string[], and those will be handled internally by sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. will try and accept as answered

Answer (score 0):

Is getdate the primitive int or the Object Integer? 
One simple way of converting an int to String is simply adding "" before the int. 
{"" + getdate, name}

If you are using the Object Integer use .toString()[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930210/java-int-to-string-integer-tostringi-vs-new-integeri-tostring)