# int array toString method that displays the values with spaces in between and a new line every ten values

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, methods

I am a beginner when it comes to java and am having some issues(been sitting in front of this all day).  I have searched far and wide for a solution, yet to no avail.  My professor has asked me to fill out the blank methods, and I am especially having trouble with the toString method(although I am not feeling to good about the rest either), any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SmartArray {
    // declare an array of ints

    int[] list;
    Random r = new Random();
    int pos = 0;

    /**
     * Creates and initializes an array of size n. It does not initialize the
     * contents of the array.
     */
    public SmartArray(int n) {
        list = new int[n];

    }

    /**
     *
     * Initializes the contents of the array with random
     *
     * non-negative* numbers.
     *
     */
    public void initRandom() {
        int i = 0;
        int hold = 0;
        while (i < list.length) {
            hold = r.nextInt();
            if (hold % 2 == 0) {
                list[i] = hold;
                i++;
            } else {
                hold = hold + 1;
                list[i] = hold;
                i++;
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Allows client code to add an element to the array
     *
     * at the given position. Throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
     *
     * exception with a message if the
     *
     * position is out of bounds.
     *
     */
    public void insert(int value, int pos) {
        if (list.length > pos) {
            list[pos] = value;
        } else {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("The position of your value is greater than the array");

        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Returns the position of target if target is
     *
     * one of the values in the array, otherwise -1.
     *
     * Implemented with a loop.
     *
     */
    public int find(int target) {
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] == target) {
                position = i;
            } else {
                position = -1;
            }
        }
        return position;

    }

    /**
     *
     * Same as the find method, except that it's implemented
     *
     * using recursion. (Hint: use a helper method.)
     *
     */
    public int recursiveFind(int pos, int target) {
        if (pos >= list.length) {
            return -1;
        } else if (list[pos] == target) {
            return pos;
        } else {
            return recursiveFind(pos + 1, target);
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * Returns the elements of the array, separated by
     *
     * spaces, with a newline after every 10 elements,
     *
     * so they can be easily displayed.
     *
     */
    public String toString() {
        String listString = "";
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            //list[i].toString();
            listString = listString + (String) list[i] + " ";
            pos++;
            if (pos > 9) {
                list = list + "\n";
                pos = 0;
            }
            return listString;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is out of OP's question, does this code even running? Where is the main part? public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Could you post what output you get by running the current code and what you expect/need the correct output to be?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public String toString() {
    String listString = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        listString += list[i - 1] + (i % 10 == 0 ? "\n" : " ");
    }
    return listString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks almost fine.

To add the newline, you should check for the remainder of the index.

You're also returning the resulting `String` inside the loop. You should only return after it.

```
public String toString() {

    String listString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        listString = listString + (String)list[i] + " ";
        if (i%9 == 0){ // if remainder of i%9 = 0, then add a newline
            list = list + "\n";
        }

    }
    return listString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give too much away since it's an academic assignment, but instead of `pos`, consider mod (`%`), which you use, so I know you're familiar with it.

Consider starting `i` at 1 and iterating through all values (no need to take 10 at a time).  But test for the need for a newline like this:

```
i % 10 == 0
```

Whenever the ith value is divisible by 10, insert a newline.

Also, consider using `Integer` instead of `int`.  In this way, you could simply do this:

```
listString = listString + list[i].toString() + " ";
```

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930249/3174746) on SO.

Good luck!