# Differrence Between strValue.toString() & strValue+"" & ""+strValue

Tags: java, android, string

Converting the value to String in java; There are multiple ways of doing it.
Just wanted to know what's the difference between each other in the following ways.

```
strValue.toString()

strValue+""

""+strValue
```

Comment: What's the type of `strValue`?

Comment: if strValue is already a string, then strValue.ToString() will return itself.

Comment: ""+strValue will internally call strValue.toString(), So technically there is no diff between them.

Comment: This is already well explained in answer and question over [HERE ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105331/how-to-convert-from-int-to-string) and again [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930210/java-int-to-string-integer-tostringi-vs-new-integeri-tostring)

Answer (score 2):

One major difference is how `null` is handled.

If `strValue` is `null`, `strValue.toString()` will throw a `NullPointerException`, while the other two options will return the String `"null"`.

Other differences may be observed if `strValue` is of a boxed numeric type, and you try to concatenate other numeric variables to it.

For example :

If

```
Integer a = 5;
Integer strValue = 6;
```

Then

```
a+strValue+""
```

would return

```
"11"
```

while

```
a+""+strValue
```

or

```
""+a+strValue
```

would return

```
"56"
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on java version. Java 7 would act a bit smarter using StringBuilder + append().

Generally, you do not want unnecessary allocations. Use first one.

Answer (score 2):

```
strValue.toString()
```

will return itself, because the `toString()` implementation of `String` (I'm guessing `strValue` is indeed of type `String`) returns `this`.

```
strValue+""

""+strValue
```

Will result in the same value (`strValue`) but won't invoke the `toString()` method

Comment: It will. + operator is overwrited for Strings and its based on invoking object's .toString() method which is inherited from *Object*

Answer (score 2):

All Strings contain the same value, try it out:

```
String strValue = "Hello world"; // not null
String a = strValue.toString();
String b = strValue+"";
String c = ""+strValue;
```

Measuring its length give all the result `11`, because adding an empty String to another one equals the original String itself:

```
System.out.println(a.length());    
...
```

Try the equality between these Strings:

```
System.out.println(a.equals(b));    
System.out.println(b.equals(c)); 
System.out.println(c.equals(a));
```

They are all `true`, because these Strings have the same value to be compared. All it in the case the `strValue` is not `null`.