# I am trying to add a String to a Method but an error is returned, what am I missing?

Tags: java

I am fairly new to programming. . .

I am getting an error with the following code :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int highScore = calculateScore(true, 800, 5, 100);
    System.out.println("Your final score was " + highScore);


    highScore = calculateScore(true, 10000, 8, 200);
    System.out.println("Your final score was " + highScore);

    displayHighScore(Jack, 3);
}

public static int calculateScore(boolean gameOver, int score, int levelCompleted, int bonus) {
    if (gameOver) {
        int finalScore = score + (levelCompleted * bonus);
        finalScore += 2000;
        return finalScore;
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void displayHighScore(String playersName, int position){
    System.out.println(playersName + " managed to get to position " + position);
   }  }
```

Comment: [The method is correct](http://ideone.com/nXlIH1). How do you call it?

Comment: (14, 26) means that the error is a line 14, column 26. That's where you should look at (and post).

Comment: you're probably calling the method with wrong parameters

Comment: Where is line 14 in your code?

Comment: Shouldn't `Jack` be in `""`?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I believe that's a typo(or we'll get different compiler message), hmmm other than this your code looks fine to me, did you forget to save the file or something ? are you sure there isn't any code other than that ?

Comment: This code compiles. Jack's score was 3300, and also 13600. His position was 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we dont have enough information but 
inspecting the error msg

> Error:(14, 26) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to
>   java.lang.String

it looks like the problem is about HOW you are calling the method you wrote...

you are passing an integer where a string must be passed...

look at the signature and give as parameter exactly what the method needs...

a `String` and an `int`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayHighScore(2, 1);  // for example this is a wrong paramerer error
    displayHighScore("C. Bryan", 1);  // this is ok!

}

public static void displayHighScore(String playersName, int position) {
    System.out.println(playersName + " managed to get to position " + position);

}
```

Answer (score -8):

Try changing to:

`System.out.println(playersName + " managed to get to position " + position.toString());`

Java doesn't coalesce to string -- you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Wrong, java does it for you. [Example](http://ideone.com/nXlIH1)

Comment: java does coalesce to string, and position isn't object, it's primitive

Comment: Eh, my bad. But I can tell what's wrong then -- the poster has asked about adding a string parameter. So he/she is still calling with the original integer value passed as the first parameter.

Comment: @daf That's my thought too, but we cannot know. That's why we are asking for clarifications in comments

Comment: This is rubbish. `int.toString()` does not exist. It is `Integer.toString(int)`.

Comment: The integer object (like all objects, afaik) has a .toString() method...

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I think he thought java was same as C#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930210/java-int-to-string-integer-tostringi-vs-new-integeri-tostring

Comment: @daf yes, but int is not an object, it's a primitive type. [See here](http://ideone.com/TVTGql)

Comment: though I'll be the first to point out that my java-fu is way < my C#-fu; my sum experience of java has been in writing android apps.

Comment: @daf `int i;new Integer(i).toString()` is different than `int i; i.toString()`, the latter won't compile :)

Comment: @C.Bell you can edit your question and put that in it :)

Comment: Working now, thanks all!