# Create new Node for Singly Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am still learning Java, and currently working problems from Cracking the Coding Interview, and one of the problems on Chapter-2 (LinkedList) asks to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked List. I found a bunch of answers/solution on GitHub, but I would like to create my own Node, and write my own version.

What I have implemented so far is that I created Node class and write the function/method that can remove the duplicates from unsorted LinkedList, but when I try to test it, I tried to create the LinkedList in the main function, but I still have no idea how to figure it out. Can someone please help/guide me how to create a Singly LinkedList? 
Basically, I create four nodes (fourth,third,second,head), and connect them all using the Node class.

Thanks in advance,

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return data + "";
    }
}


public class problem1 {

    public void Remove_duplicates(Node head){
        if(head == null){
            return;
        }

        Node current = head;
        while(current != null){
            Node runner = current;
            while(runner.next != null){
                if(runner.next.data == current.data){
                    runner.next = runner.next.next;
                }
                else {
                    runner = runner.next;
                }
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node fourth = new Node(5,null);
        Node third = new Node(3,fourth);
        Node second = new Node(4,third);
        Node head = new Node(3,second);
        for(Node a: head){
            // ERROR: saying can only iterate over an array (or) java.lang.Iterable
            System.out.println(a.toString());
            a = a.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return data + "";` Blah. Try `return Integer.toString(data);`

Comment: @bradimus the code `return data + "";` should work.

Comment: It will work, but "will work" and "good style" are not synonymous. Read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930210/java-int-to-string-integer-tostringi-vs-new-integeri-tostring)

Comment: @bradimus it would also be possible to use `String.valueOf(data)`. so what is the better style? - I would suggest the second one because when you change from `int` to `double` it still works.

Comment: `String.valueOf(data‌​)` is equally good. `data + ""` does not express clear intent where as `String.valueOf(data‌​)` and `Integer.toString(dat‌​a)` do. Read through the question I liked. Some of the answers/comments address this as well as the efficiency of the statements.

Comment: @bradimus Yep a good advice! - But next time it would  be good when you add a reason in your comment why the code change should be done, so everyone would understand it :-)

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, but I got it working since I was using foreach loop instead of while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try another kind of loop e.g. `while`

```
Node head = new Node(3, second);
Node node = head;
while (node.next != null) {
    System.out.println(node.toString());
    node = node.next;
}
```

Like it explains it does not know how to iterate over your nodes.
Another approach for using the `foreach` would be to create an own class which implements the interface `Iterable` and does contain your `LinkedList` logic.

For the second approach I would suggest you to read the following: [How can I implement the Iterable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601658/how-can-i-implement-the-iterable-interface)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I didn't realize that I need to create an own class to use foreach loop.